# PyAudio gives no output in the recording file despite using the appropriate input device

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

I am trying to use pyaudio to record audio but with the program I have it does not have any output

I use input_device_index = 0 which is my computers microphone. I have tried connecting to bluetooth headphones but this gives an error since the CHUNK variable needs to be changed. This is my code currently:

```
def record(outputFile):
    CHUNK = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 2
    RATE = 44100
    RECORD_SECONDS = 2

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, input_device_index = 0,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    print("* recording")

    frames = []

    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)

    print("* done recording")

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

    wf = wave.open(outputFile, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()
```

I try to record a test file with a lot of sound but I just get a file with no sound at all. Does anyone know the issue?